# How to run subtasks multiple times in rake multitask?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

So I have

`multitask :do_something => [
    :task1,
    :task2,
    :task3,
    :task4,
    :task5,
    :task6
]`

And each task runs a script. I want the tasks1 to task6 concurrently to run 1000 times without stopping. Is there a way it can be achieved?